# Rails exclude record with null association from class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On my Item model I have this method:

```
  def sold_units
    (self.item_movements.sales.sum(:quantity) / self.unit_sell.quantity)
  end
```

Unit sell is the unit on which item is sold, like grams or kilograms, which belong to Unit.

```
  belongs_to :unit_sell, :class_name => 'Unit', :foreign_key => 'sell_unit', optional: true
```

unit_sell.quantity is the quantity of reference unit. Basically the method converts units sold to reference unit.

Not every item has unit_sell. For some item the value is null.

Hence if I run the method I get:

```
undefined method `quantity' for nil:NilClass
```

On ItemMovement model I have

```
scope :sales, -> { where(reason: -1) }
```

which filters item movements that are sales. For these movements, item unit_sell is always not null.

How to exclude records with association null?

Comment: You can filter off nil values.

Comment: What should `sold_units` return if `self.unit_sell.nil?`? Or, what should `quantity` be when there is no `unit_sell`?

Comment: It should return 0. Basically items for which unit_sell is null should have sold_units = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it this way:

```
  def sold_units
    item_unit_sell_quantity = self.unit_sell.present? ? self.unit_sell.quantity : 0
    (self.item_movements.sales.sum(:quantity) / (item_unit_sell_quantity))
  end
```